# C return array pointers from two different c files for use in a function with no global's allowed

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am writing a C assignment for one of my university modules. I am trying to return pointers to two arrays (1 array from each c file) for use in a function in a different c file. I will then do the correct calculations on said arrays.

The current problem i am facing:

**Note: the code below has has been simplified to be more readable the main elements are still in place**

1. The assignment restricts the use of global variables
2. one array is in a file mayday.c
3. one array is in a file ships.c
4. the function call is in a file system_handler.c

I need to be able to return the arrays from 2 and 3, for use in function in 4.

the code is:

mayday.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mayday.h"
#include "rescue_assets.h"
#include "ship.h"

void assign_mayday_to_ships() {

mayday_call* m_ptr; 
ship* sh_ptr;

 /*correct operations on the arrays */


 }
```

ships.c

```
 void read_ship_locations() {
 ship ships[10];
/* fill array methods removed */
ret_ship_array(ships);
}

ship* ret_ship_array(ship ships[]) {
return ships;
}
```

The function call i am trying to use the two array's with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mayday.h"
#include "rescue_assets.h"
#include "ship.h"

void assign_mayday_to_ships() {

mayday_call* m_ptr; 
ship* sh_ptr;

 /*correct operations on the arrays */

 }
```

The assign_mayday_to_ships will use pointers which will be results on the return array methods from mayday.c and ship.c but i am unsure how to implement this.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: I dont understand what assign_mayday_to_ships() is supposed to do... Can you please clarify?

Comment: @ScottyBauer i have not yet implemented it but basically a ship has a mayday call assigned to it, so i am going to pass in both arrays and match the mayday call to the ship based on the mayday info, i know how to do this but i don't know how to access the arrays.

Comment: "The assignment restricts the use of global variables" What does that *mean*? That you *have* to use global arrays but cannot refer to them in your functions? That you *cannot* use global arrays, rather only local arrays and they must be passed to your functions as parameters? that you cannot use arrays *at all* and must instead use dynamic allocation?

Comment: @WhozCraig i think it just means no global variables at all, so no use of global arrays, arrays must be passed to functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think I understand what you're asking.

A few things:
Since you're not allowed to store global variables the array will have to be calculated on the fly, and stored in the heap. The reason why you can't store the arrays on the stack is once the function returns that data is out of scope and accessing it would be undefined behavior.

Your code should look like this:

```
 ship* read_ship_locations() {
   //allocate 10 spaces for ships on the heap
   ship ships* = malloc(10 * sizeof(ship));
   //Always check malloc for a null pointer meaning it could not allocate memory!
   if(!ships){
     perror("malloc fail");
   }
   /* fill array methods removed */
  return ships;
 }
```

The other method is very similar.

Then for assign you would could the following:

```
void assign_mayday_to_ships() {

  mayday_call* m_ptr;
  ship* sh_ptr;

  m_ptr = assign_mayday_to_ships();
  sh_ptr = read_ship_locations();
  /*correct operations on the arrays */

  //You can then access the pointers as if they're arrays. BUT note you must either kepe the size constant (10) or else you're going to be doing undefined behavior by accessing outside of array bounds.

  //an example:
  ship test_ship = sh_ptr[0];
  test_ship.mayday = m_ptr[0];
  sh_ptr[0] = test_ship;

  //or do everything in place
  sh_ptr[0].mayday = m_ptr[0];


}
```

Note, in order to keep from having a memory leak, once you're done with the m_ptr and sh_ptr you must free them.